Definite way to move between columns in Word VBA (no tables)
I feel like this is ridiculously simple, but I have not been able to find any definite answer for moving between columns in word that are NOT in a table. I have this document with 8 columns and have tried to do things like Selection.MoveRight Unit:= wdColumn, Count:=2 which gives a Bad parameter error and Selection.MoveRight Unit:= wdColumn, Count:=2 which doesn't do anything.
I tried to use the move functions with other units, but none worked.
If the doc had 2 columns, it would look something like this:
(end of first col)
aaaaa  |  aaaaa
aaaaa  |  aaaaa
aaaaa  |  aaaaa
aaaaa  |  aaaaa



The values wdCell, wdColumn, wdRow all relate to tables. A document with text columns simply flows text from the bottom of one column to the top of the next.

So, there's no way to go from one column to another if there's not a table?

Why do you need to between columns? What exactly are you trying to do?

I have word files which are generated by a software, and theres multiple columns with categories of datas (example im making up: name and age). And when getting a certain name, i need to get the corresponding age.

If you open the document in Word and select one line, does the selection extend across all 8 “columns”? If so you don’t have any columns in the document, just text arranged into a pseudo table, probably using tabs to keep the data aligned in a columnar format. If that is the case then you’ll need something similar to the suggestion by jonsson

Nope, I have to go all the way down to get to the next column.

A multi-column layout doesn't really have a concept of one piece of text being to the right of another. Text simply flows from one column into the next. By far the easiest approach in your situation would be to convert the columns into a table, and then use wdColumn.

@Paul - converting the text to a table wouldn't help as the result would just be a single column table.

Can you go back to the originators of the software and ask them to format the data in a table, or even just tab separated so that you can convert it into a table?

@TimothyRylatt You are right, the regular Convert Text to Table wouldn't work. You'd have to write a bit of VBA to do the conversion (which is easy if they included column breaks, a bit more complicated if they didn't)

I don't see any column breaks. Right now, I'm going back to the top of the column, counting how many rows I went up, switch the column and go back down the same amount of rows. Sometimes, though, there's unreadable characters and it's messed up.

"I don't see any column breaks" - do you have non-printing characters shown?

Not sure what problems you are running into now but it seems to me that the following is a viable approach, assuming all your data really is in a "tabular format", so e.g. paragraph 5 in one column is in the same logical row as paragraph 5 in every other column.
Starting from the current selection (say),
set a range to the selection
move up until you reach the previous section, the previous page, or the beginning of the document
Now you can move to the beginning of your section/page
move down, storing each paragraph's text in a global/module level array, using textcolumn info and range.information to determine when you move to the next column. Continue until you reach a new section, new page, or end of document.
This won't work as is if you are modifying the text as you go, and not much use if you are hopping from page to page, but maybe viable if you are (for example) processing everything in sequence).
e.g. something like this:
Option Explicit
Const InitialCdataRows As Long = 30
Const MoreCdataRows As Long = 10
Public cdata() As String


Sub TextColumnDataToArray(StartRange As Word.Range)
' Starts with the section where StartRange.Start is located, and
' loads the content of that section that's on the current page
' into cdata.

' This obviously requires that *all* the paragraphs inthe section
' are similar in the sense that they look like a table, so e.g.
' para 5 is column 2 is in the same "table row" as para 5 in column 1

Dim ColumnEnds() As Single
Dim CurrentSection As Long
Dim CurrentPage As Long
Dim hpos As Single ' horizontal position
Dim tc As Long ' textcolumn index
Dim tcc As Long ' textcolumn count
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

With StartRange
  .Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart

  ' Get info about our columns and page
  CurrentPage = .Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
  CurrentSection = .Sections(1).Index
  With .Sections(1).PageSetup
    tcc = .TextColumns.Count
    ReDim ColumnEnds(1 To tcc) As Single
    ColumnEnds(1) = .LeftMargin + .TextColumns(1).Width + .TextColumns(1).SpaceAfter
    For tc = 2 To tcc - 1
      ColumnEnds(tc) = ColumnEnds(tc - 1) + .TextColumns(tc).Width + .TextColumns(tc).SpaceAfter
    Next
    ColumnEnds(tcc) = ColumnEnds(tcc - 1) + .TextColumns(tc).Width
  End With
  ReDim cdata(1 To InitialCdataRows, 1 To tcc) As String

  ' move up until we are either in the previous section (on the same page)
  ' or on the previous page, or in the 1st para in the document

  Do Until (.Sections(1).Index < CurrentSection) _
           Or (.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) < CurrentPage) _
           Or (.Start = 0)
    .Move WdUnits.wdParagraph, -1
  Loop
  
  ' Ensure we are at the start of page/section
  If (.Sections(1).Index < CurrentSection) _
           Or (.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) <> CurrentPage) Then
    .Move WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1
  End If
  
  x = 0
  y = 1
  
  Do
      If .Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) < ColumnEnds(y) Then
        x = x + 1
      Else
        y = y + 1
        x = 1
      End If
      If x > UBound(cdata, 1) Then
        ReDim Preserve cdata(1 To x + MoreCdataRows, 1 To y) As String
      End If
      cdata(x, y) = Left(.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, Len(.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text) - 1)
      .Move WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1
      DoEvents
  Loop Until (.Sections(1).Index > CurrentSection) _
       Or (.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > CurrentPage) _
       Or (.End + 1 >= .Document.Content.End)
End With

End Sub

Sub filldata()
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Call TextColumnDataToArray(Selection.Range)
Debug.Print LBound(cdata, 1), UBound(cdata, 1)
For x = LBound(cdata, 1) To UBound(cdata, 1)
  For y = LBound(cdata, 2) To UBound(cdata, 2)
    Debug.Print x, y; cdata(x, y)
  Next
Next
End Sub

